# When using the "Pre Token Generation Lambda Trigger Function", how do I set the "claimsToAddOrOverride" to return an array instead of a string

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk

I've written a Pre Token Generation Lambda Trigger function to split a custom string attribute into an array and assign to a new attribute, the string attribute would be in this format "FDVC443FD|HFVSD4434". The lambda function should then create the array ["FDVC443FD", "HFVSD4434"] and assigned it to the new attribute.

Expected Result Input -> "custom:eaid": "FDVC443FD|HFVSD4434" Output -> "eaid": ["FDVC443FD", "HFVSD4434"]

Pre Token Generation Lambda Trigger Function (Python)

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
#This function handles adding a custom claim to the cognito ID token.# grab requestor's custom external id (eaid)
custom_eaid = event['request']['userAttributes']['custom:eaid']

# Split the custom attribute string into an array by the "|" seperator
custom_eaid = custom_eaid.split('|')

# placeholder variable
eaid = ''

# this allows us to override claims in the id token
# "claimsToAddOrOverride" is the important part 
event["response"]["claimsOverrideDetails"] = { 
    "claimsToAddOrOverride": { 
        "eaid": custom_eaid
    },
    "claimsToSuppress": ["custom:eaid"]
} 
     
# return modified ID token to Amazon Cognito 
return event
```

The Lambda function returns the following error:-

Error executing "InitiateAuth" on "https://cognito-idp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com\ "; AWS HTTP error: Client error: POST https://cognito-idp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com  resulted in a 400 Bad Request response:\n{"__type":"InvalidLambdaResponseException","message":"Unrecognizable lambda output"}\n InvalidLambdaResponseException (client): Unrecognizable lambda output - {"__type":"InvalidLambdaResponseException","message":"Unrecognizable lambda output"}

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-token-generation.html#cognito-user-pools-lambda-trigger-syntax-pre-token-generation), `claimsToAddOrOverride` expects a collection of `string` key/value pairs.

So as of now we can not pass a list as a value.

Maybe you can try, a comma separated string or set the `custom:eaid` as it is. Then whenever you need that as a list, extract that from the claim.

Comment: any reason to not support this? Though this is supported in role overrides and group overrides, as mentioned here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-token-generation.html